# Cadastro e Widgets personalizados em Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget

Temos um site em Wordpress já em funcionamento e precisamos desenvolver uma funcionalidade no mesmo que possibilite o seguinte:

1. Permitir a um DJ fazer um cadastro e criar o seu perfil no site;
2. Criar uma página que mostre as informações de um determinado DJ. Nessa página preciso de um widget que mostre as músicas preferidas desse DJ, um outro widget que mostre os últimos cadastrados e mais um widget com os mais acessados.

Não tenho experiencia com Wordpress, mas sim com PHP e MySQL.

Existem componentes para isso? Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?